# Fetching articles form Liferay portal

Tags: java, soap, service, liferay, portal

Our goal is to fetch some of the content from Liferay Portal via SOAP services using Java. We are successfully loading articles right now with JournalArticleServiceSoap. The problem is that the method requires both group id and entry id, and what we want is to fetch all of the articles from a particular group. Hence, we are trying to get the ids first, using AssetEntryServiceSoap but it fails.

```
AssetEntryServiceSoapServiceLocator aesssLocator = new AssetEntryServiceSoapServiceLocator();
    com.liferay.client.soap.portlet.asset.service.http.AssetEntryServiceSoap assetEntryServiceSoap = null;

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:8080/tunnel-web/secure/axis/Portlet_Asset_AssetEntryService");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        assetEntryServiceSoap = aesssLocator
                .getPortlet_Asset_AssetEntryService(url);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (assetEntryServiceSoap == null) {
        return;
    }

    Portlet_Asset_AssetEntryServiceSoapBindingStub assetEntryServiceSoapBindingStub = (Portlet_Asset_AssetEntryServiceSoapBindingStub) assetEntryServiceSoap;
    assetEntryServiceSoapBindingStub.setUsername("bruno@7cogs.com");
    assetEntryServiceSoapBindingStub.setPassword("bruno");

    AssetEntrySoap[] entries;
    AssetEntryQuery query = new AssetEntryQuery();

    try {
        int count = assetEntryServiceSoap.getEntriesCount(query);
        System.out.println("Entries count: " + Integer.toString(count));
        entries = assetEntryServiceSoap.getEntries(query);
        if (entries != null) {
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(entries.length));
        }
        for (AssetEntrySoap aes : assetEntryServiceSoap.getEntries(query)) {
            System.out.println(aes.getEntryId());
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Although getEntriesCount() returns a positive value like 83, getEnries() always returns an empty array. I'm very new to Liferay portal, but it looks really weird to me.

By the way, we are obviously not looking for performance here, the key is just to fetch some specific content from the portal remotely. If you know any working solution your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, I traced the code and found that, by sending plain object of AssetEntryQuery(), you might not have accurate query. Have a look at method findEntries(AssetEntryQuery entryQuery) entry of com.liferay.portlet.asset.service.persistence.AssetEntryFinderImpl

Answer (score 0):

Normally a AssetEntryQuery would have a little more information in it for example:

```
AssetEntryQuery assetEntryQuery = new AssetEntryQuery();
assetEntryQuery.setClassNameIds(new long[] { ClassNameLocalServiceUtil.getClassNameId("com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle") });
assetEntryQuery.setGroupIds(new long[] { groupId });
```

So this would return all AssetEntries for the groupId you specify, that are also JournalArticles.

Try this and see, although as you say, the Count method returns a positive number so it might not make a difference, but give it a go! :)